# Remove Middle fragment from FragmentStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I want to remove middle fragment of fragment stack. i.e I have stack with Fragments A, B, C, D
in this case i want to remove B or C without removed D.

Is there any way to do that? because if i remove D and re-added it after removing B or C it will take time to create view and add all details again.

Comment: what have you done so far? put a code piece that you've worked on so we can better help you.

Comment: @OnurA. sorry to not written any code i just used "add", "hide" and  "remove" methods of fragment transection. Thanks for the replay!

Answer (score 3):

Use tags while calling the fragments with each fragment having a unique tag. Then remove fragments from fragment stack by using this tag.

Switch between fragments like this:

```
 public void switchContent(final Fragment fragment, final String TAG) {
        CgUtils.showLog(TAG, "in switchcontent with fragment passed " + fragment);
        mContentFragment = fragment;
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, TAG)
                        .commitAllowingStateLoss();
                fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
                getSlidingMenu().showContent();
                // .commit();
            }
        }, 50);
    }
```

e.g :

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)).commit();
```

Comment: Quite different than what i thought, but i need to give it a shot, my actual problem is i have to handle backstack after selection of next fragment by the user, BTW @user2564055 Thanks for the quick replay :)

Comment: .remove is working to remove fragment in between stack but still BackStackEntry is there so when press back that will affect as blank fragment. at the time of adding fragment i always need to add that to backstack..